# Facing some errors after deploying code to heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I got the following errors after deploying my code to heroku through the heroku CLI:

```
2019-01-21T21:46:43.673884+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=testmkyoung.herokuapp.com request_id=0ff8d9be-b6d5-437e-99c0-1133a9dc0a1d fwd="204.14.239.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-21T21:46:44.773150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=testmkyoung.herokuapp.com request_id=301a9b63-5c56-4214-bc4e-643ff7f37a8a fwd="204.14.239.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-01-21T21:47:05.216113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=testmkyoung.herokuapp.com request_id=f25fbffe-9524-4e46-a239-d294ea946b50 fwd="204.14.239.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Can someone tell me how to debug it?